# Problem connecting to Bloomberg via SSL QuickFixJ

Tags: java, ssl, bloomberg, quickfixj

I am unable to connect to Bloomberg via QuickFixJ.

The error message is :

```
MINA session created: local=/10.150.2.120:36078, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketSession, remote=/69.191.198.38:8228
Initiated logon request
Disconnecting: Socket exception (/69.191.198.38:8228): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
Session FIXT.1.1:ARHGBETA->BBGBETA schedule is daily, 00:00:00-UTC - 00:00:00-UTC
```

However, I have configured my configuration file with the documentation, credentials and certificates Bloomberg gave me and by using the documentation on QuickFixJ available here : https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/quickfixlogs
FileLogPath=target/data/quickfixlogs
ConnectionType=initiator

[session]
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SenderCompID=******
TargetCompID=******
HeartBtInt=60
ReconnectInterval=5
SocketConnectPort=8228
SocketConnectHost=69.191.198.38
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
CheckLatency=N
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=.\cert.pfx
SocketKeyStorePassword=************
KeyStoreType=PKCS12
CipherSuites=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Can someone help me please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `CipherSuites=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` - I cannot see this line documented in the link you referenced. And it does not look like to me that the site actually supports the given cipher. Where does this configuration line and specifically the value comes from? Maybe just delete it.

Comment: Also please try to specify an absolute path to the key store. We usually convert the key store to JKS.

Comment: Many thanks for your help ! For the CipherSuites mentionned above, it can be found using the link below :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html
Moreover, I tried removing the CipherSuites and changing the .pfx file to the .jks file with its associated password Bloomberg furnishes. And yet, I'm still having the same problem. Do you know if there is any further configuration that need to be done to add SSL to QuickFixJ?

Comment: It works for us with those settings. You could only try to ask Bloomberg if they see something on their side or you could enable SSL debug logging.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply John, I will check with Bloomberg. Are you using Stunnel in addition to QuickFix?

Comment: I have modified the certificate type and am now encountering a END_OF_STREAM error

Comment: No, we are not using STunnel since QuickFIX/J natively supports SSL/TLS.

Comment: @user16806803 Did you find a solution for your problem?